# World map longtidue does not match with my data using the packages of rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I use the packages of rworldmap to visualize netcdf file. The longitude of netcdf file is from 0-360, but the default longitude format of rworldmap is 0-360, I have change netcdf file longitude using the following code.

```
for (n in 1:nc$dim$lon$len) {
    nc$dim$lon$vals[n] = nc$dim$lon$vals[n] - 180
}
```

But the map still has some problem. Map longtidue does not match with my data.

Comment: What are the cartographic projections used in both data sources?

Comment: You need to show the code that does the plotting and reading data, and the plot. It might be non-regular coordinates but at least you need to swap the grid as well as the lone. And you need to swap the lons not just offset them, but there are other ways too.